# Map typescript array elements to keyof object, recursively

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, typescript-types

I'd like to express a path lookup for objects, with a type that ensures that the path is correctly typed based on an object type.

It's probably best to explain with an example. Given this, or any similar data:

```
const obj = {
    name: 'Test',
    city: { name: 'London' },
    tags: [
        { name: 'tag1' }, { name: 'tag2' }
    ]
}
```

I'd like to have this kind of type:

```
type FieldPath<typeof obj, [maybe other parameters]>
```

That should ensure these constraints:

```
// keyof access
const path1 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['name']

// Doesn't exist
const path2 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['nope'] // Error: Type 'nope' is not assignable to...

// Nested object access
const path3 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['city', 'name']

// Doesn't exist (on city)
const path4 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['city', 'nope'] // Error: Type 'nope' is not assignable to...

// Array access
const path5 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['tags', 1]

// Invalid keyof access
const path6 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['tags', 'nope'] // Error: Type 'nope' is not assignable to...

// Keep going recursively
const path7 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['tags', 1, 'name']

// With failures
const path8 : FieldPath<typeof obj> = ['tags', 1, 'nope'] // Error: Type 'nope' is not...
```

Is this possible?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8XyMw) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible at the moment since the compiler cannot handle such cases. For example, if the valid options are these: `['a', 'subA'] | ['b', 'subB']` you will still be able to write something like this: `['a', 'b']`. There is an alternative approach with the path being in dot notation (`a.subA`). If that fits your case please consider using the following solution.

To actually get the paths in dot notation we will need a type to generate those:

```
// If there SubPath then return 'BasePath.SubPath', otherwise return BasePath'
type Dot<BasePath extends string, SubPath extends string> = '' extends SubPath
  ? BasePath
  : `${BasePath}.${SubPath}`;
```

We will also add stop conditions, for example on which types we should stop. In our case, we want to stop on primitive types `number | string | boolean`.

Therefore we declare the following type:

```
type DefaultTargetFields = number | string | boolean;
```

The last part is the traverse function:

```
type PathsToFields<Obj, TargetFields = DefaultTargetFields> = Obj extends TargetFields
  ? ''
  : {
      [K in keyof Obj & string]: Dot<K, PathsToFields<Obj[K], TargetFields>>;
    }[keyof Obj & string];
```

It takes two arguments, the object that we are traversing and the types that we are looking for (defaulted to the `DefaultTargetFields`).

We first check if the `Obj` is the type that we are looking for (`Obj extends TargetFields`). If that's true we return an empty string indicating that the path ends here. Otherwise we loop through the string keys of Obj and call `Dot` type with `BasePath = K` and the `SubPath = PathsToFields<Obj[K], TargetFields>>`.
`PathsToFields<Obj[K], TargetFields>>` is recursively calling to sub-properties of the `Obj`

Usage:

```
// type B = "name" | "city.name" | "tags.length" | "tags.0.name" | "tags.1.name"
type B = PathsToFields<typeof obj>;
```

Link to [playground](https://tsplay.dev/WkE6DN)

Comment: Hey, many thanks for this! Unfortunately the data cannot be const, since I have to allow arbitrary index lookups: `tags.100.name`. I had hoped it would be possible to check the rest elements of the array, and if it's a number then infer the value of the parent, but it doesn't seem so.

Comment: Please check the [playground](https://tsplay.dev/m0zjDw) to see if it fits your need. if the array is not readonly you can pass any index, unfortunately, index will not be autocompleted because it accepts any number, however, it will still check if you are accessing the correct property of that element. 
`tags.1.name // no error`, but `tags.1.surname //error`.

If this is what you need let me now and I will update the answer

Comment: "if the valid options are these: `['a', 'subA'] | ['b', 'subB']` you will still be able to write something like this: `['a', 'b']`" That doesn't look right. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Thanks for noting; what I meant is that IDE will suggest to you the options that are not valid. For instance, if I type `['city']`, my IDE suggests to me `'0' | '1' | 'name'`, even though the type checking will work, it is still confusing to see those in the autosuggestions. [playground](https://tsplay.dev/NVYVGw)

Comment: The same goes with your [approach](https://tsplay.dev/w8XyMw) here. I would prefer not to see incorrect suggestions and `split` the string path to get the same array of path

Comment: Oh, this looks very good! Again, many thanks for your type wizardry. :)

Comment: I went for the `DynamicType` approach, much nicer than the array version.